# Kodaira dimension of a singular determinantal hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have $X$ a determinantal hypersurface of degree $d\geqslant 5$ in $\mathbb{P}^4$. As far as I know, a generic such determinantal hypersurface is singular with finitely many singularities. I want to compute the Kodaira dimension of this hypersurface, i.e. the Kodaira dimension of some resolution of singularities of $X$.

I know that if my hypersurface were smooth, then the Kodaira dimension would be $0$ for $d=5$ and $3$ for $d>5$. However, I don't really know how resolutions of singularities work, still kind of learning algebraic geometry as I go.

Or is something known about the Kodaira dimension of determinantal hypersurfaces in general?

Not sure if this question is more fitting for mathoverflow, decided it was too narrow for that site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a general determinantal hypersurface $X$ there is a natural resolution of singularities $\pi \colon \tilde{X} \to X$, called Springer resolution, which is small, that is its exceptional locus has codimension $\ge 2$. This means that
$$
K_{\tilde{X}} = \pi^*K_X = (d-5)\pi^*H,
$$
where $H$ is the hyperplane class of $X$. Thus, if $d = 5$ the canonical class of $\tilde{X}$ is trivial, hence Kodaira dimension is zero, and if $d > 5$ it is nef and big, hence Kodaira dimension is the maximal possible, that is 3.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of a reference where I could learn about this resolution? I've been trying for a few hours with no avail.

Comment: I don't know a good reference but the construction is as follows. A determinantal hypersurface in $X$ is the degeneracy locus $D(f)$ for a morphism $f \colon E \to F$ of vector bundles of the same rank. The Springer resolution of $D(f)$ is the subvariety $\tilde{D}(f)$ of the projective bundle $\mathbb{P}_X(E)$ parameterizing pairs $(x,e)$, where $x \in X$ and $e \in \mathbb{P}(E_x)$ such that $f_x(e) = 0$. When $f$ is suficiently general, $\tilde{D}(f)$ is smooth and birational to $D(f)$.

Comment: Thank you! I also happened upon a reference, leaving it here for future visitors: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.00929.pdf, Proposition 3.6

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but could you please expand on the computation of $K_{\tilde{X}}$? I understand the second equality for a non-singular hypersurface $X$, but for the singular case, I am not even sure that this notation means. For instance, what is $K_X$ here? I am only used to the definition of the canonical class for non-singular varieties.

Comment: @Serge: For singular (normal) variety $X$ the canonical class is defined as the Weil divisor class corresponding to the canonical class of the smooth locus of $X$. The equality $K_{\tilde{X}} = \pi^*K_X$ follows from the fact that the smooth locus of $X$ is isomorphic (via $\pi^{-1}$) to an open subset of $\tilde{X}$ with complement of codimension greater than 1.

Comment: I was mostly confused about the second equality. I was studying this in Hartshorne, and Hartshorne shows that it holds for a nonsingular hypersurface $X$. I feel like there should be some obvious reason why this should hold, for example, for the smooth locus of a singular hypersurface, but I don't see it yet.

Comment: This is just the adjunction formula that works for any normal hypersurface. To prove it just consider $X \setminus Sing(X)$ in $\mathbb{P}^4 \setminus Sing(X)$, this is now a smooth hypersurface in a smooth variety, and then apply the smooth adjunction formula to find the canonical class of $X \setminus Sing(X)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it now! Didn't think of cutting out $Sing(X)$ out of the projective space too.